# How do you calculate data completeness for multiple tables based on null values within columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

The query below calculates what we need but for only one specific column. How can we do this for all the columns within that table, without having to duplicate the case statement multiple times. This needs to be done for hundreds of tables, so duplicating the case statement is not ideal.

```
 Select SUM(cast(case when column is null then 0 else 1 end as float))/count(*) from [Table]
```

So the output would be something like

Column Name:          Data completeness

Customer Name:            88%

Comment: You'll need to duplicate that case statement multiple times. If copy/paste isn't good enough, then you can get crafty with some dynamic SQL in a stored procedure where the SP builds your CASE statements for you dynamically.

Comment: have you tried just doing select count(column1), count(column2) from table?

Comment: could you please put some sample data and output result

Comment: We need to do this for hundreds of tables, and each table has several columns. So if there was some sort of function or easier process to do this, rather than copy/paste columns names or case statements several hundred times, that would be what we need.

Comment: You could also consider https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895263.aspx

Comment: Also, FYI, you don't need the `CASE` expression, as `COUNT(<columnName>)` only counts the non-null values anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by Jens Suessmeyer from [Finding the percentage of NULL values for each column in a table](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samlester/archive/2012/09/22/tsql-solve-it-your-way-finding-the-percentage-of-null-values-for-each-column-in-a-table.aspx)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Statement2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @FinalStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @TABLE_SCHEMA SYSNAME = <SCHEMA_NAME>
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME = <TABLE_NAME>

SELECT
        @Statement = @Statement + 'SUM(CASE WHEN ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ' + COLUMN_NAME + ',' + CHAR(13) ,
        @Statement2 = @Statement2 + COLUMN_NAME + '*100 / OverallCount AS ' + COLUMN_NAME + ',' + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @TABLE_SCHEMA

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RAISERROR('TABLE OR VIEW with schema "%s" and name "%s" does not exists or you do not have appropriate permissions.',16,1, @TABLE_SCHEMA, @TABLE_NAME)
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @FinalStatement =
            'SELECT ' + LEFT(@Statement2, LEN(@Statement2) -2) + ' FROM (SELECT ' + LEFT(@Statement, LEN(@Statement) -2) +
            ', COUNT(*) AS OverallCount FROM ' + @TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TABLE_NAME + ') SubQuery'
    EXEC(@FinalStatement)
END
```

Comment: So I didn't use the answer above, but I did use the link to find the answer that I needed.

Comment: Doesn't escape column names with square brackets - will almost certainly fail on most databases

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify the logic to:

```
Select AVG(case when column is null then 0.0 else 1.0 end)
from [Table]
```

Then, you can generate the code.  The following generates the `from` expressions.  You can copy them over into the query:

```
select replace('      avg(case when [@col] is null then 0.0 else 1.0 end) as [@col],',
               '@col', column_name)
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = @TableName and table_schema = @SchemaName
```

Note: `quotename()` is more correct, but the above should work for reasonable column names (I never have column names that need to be quoted).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  Basically build a statement that selects the count for each column out of each table, using sys.tables and sys.columns, and then execute that statement.

```
Begin
    Select @sqlcmd = 'insert into mystats (TableName, ColumnName, TotCount)
             Values (select ''' + t.name + ''', ''' + c.name + ''', count(' + c.name + ') from ' + t.name + ')'
    From sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c
    On c.object_id = t.object_id

    EXEC @sqlcmd
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNPIVOT query to do this for you, something like..... In the following query I have assumed that you have 3 columns `Column1,Column2,Column3`, the query can be extended to accommodate as many as columns.

### Query

```
SELECT ColumnName 
      , SUM(cast(case when Vals = '' then 0.0 else 1.0 end as DECIMAL(10,2))) * 100
      / COUNT(*)  AS [Percetage]
FROM (
SELECT CAST(ISNULL(Column1, '') AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Column1
      ,CAST(ISNULL(Column2, '') AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Column2
      ,CAST(ISNULL(Column3, '') AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Column3
FROM TableName
  )c
  UNPIVOT (Vals FOR ColumnName IN (Column1,Column2,Column3))up
GROUP BY ColumnName
```

### Result Set

```
╔════════════╦════════════╗
║ ColumnName ║ Percetage  ║
╠════════════╬════════════╣
║ Column1    ║ 100.000000 ║
║ Column2    ║ 100.000000 ║
║ Column3    ║ 34.065934  ║
╚════════════╩════════════╝
```

### Important Note

Make sure you convert all the columns being used in UNPIVOT IN clause to a uniform data type.

Also using `ISNULL(Column1, '')` is important as UNPIVOT eliminates any null values.

Answer (score 0):

My answer combines the sample from lad2025's answer and the `UNPIVOT` from M.Ali's answer to provide you with a result set with a row for each column containing the name of the column and the percentage of nulls.  It will show them in descending order by percentage of nulls.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Statement2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Statement3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @FinalStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @TABLE_SCHEMA SYSNAME = <SCHEMA_Name>
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME = <TABLE_Name>

SELECT
        @Statement = @Statement + 'SUM(CASE WHEN ' + COLUMN_NAME + 
            ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ' + COLUMN_NAME + ',' + CHAR(13) ,
        @Statement2 = @Statement2 + COLUMN_NAME + 
            '*100 / OverallCount AS ' + COLUMN_NAME + ',' + CHAR(13),
        @Statement3 = @Statement3 + COLUMN_NAME + ','
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @TABLE_SCHEMA

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RAISERROR('TABLE OR VIEW with schema "%s" and name "%s" does not exists or you do not have appropriate permissions.',16,1, @TABLE_SCHEMA, @TABLE_NAME)
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @FinalStatement =
            'SELECT u.ColumnName, u.NullPercentage FROM (SELECT ' + 
            LEFT(@Statement2, LEN(@Statement2) -2) + 
            ' FROM (SELECT ' + LEFT(@Statement, LEN(@Statement) -2) +
            ', COUNT(*) AS OverallCount FROM ' + @TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TABLE_NAME + 
            ') SubQuery) PercentageQuery unpivot (NullPercentage for ColumnName in (' + 
            LEFT(@Statement3, LEN(@Statement3) - 1) + 
            ')) u ORDER BY NullPercentage DESC'
    EXEC(@FinalStatement)
END
```